# How to achieve tenant-level affinity for Blazor Server application on Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am designing a multitenant application with Blazor Server. Each tenant can have multiple users all sharing some data. I want to keep this shared data in the memory of the Blazor Server process and reuse it between users of the same tenant.

It works smoothly when everything is hosted on a single machine with a single Blazor process. However, production deployment on Azure App Service will use multiple servers and processes. Default session affinity setting highlighted in Blazor documentation (e.g., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-5.0) guarantees that each circuit will stick to a single server. However, I cannot find any suggestion on sticking a **group** of users identified by some `TenantId` to the same server and process.

Is it possible to achieve with Azure App Service deployment?

Comment: Since affinity is an aspect of load balancing and having clumps of sessions stick to one server defeats that intent, not likely a way to do this via session affinity. Since instances are always subject to be restarted anyway, better to design with assumption of sessions hitting any instance and cache accordingly

Comment: Blazor Server is already implying a stateful application model for each individual client. I am merely seeking how to extend it from an individual client to a group of clients.